# How to connect spark application to secure HBase with Kerberos

Tags: authentication, apache-spark, hbase, kerberos

I`m trying to connect a Spark application to HBase with Kerberos enabled. Spark version is 1.5.0, CDH 5.5.2 and it's executed in yarn cluster mode.

When HbaseContext is initialized, it throws this error:

> ERROR ipc.AbstractRpcClient: SASL authentication failed. The most likely cause is missing or invalid credentials. Consider 'kinit'.
>   javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]

I have tried to do the authentication in the code, adding:

```
UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(config)
UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(principalName, keytabFilename)
```

I distribute the keytab file with --files option in spark-submit.
Now, the error is:

> java.io.IOException: Login failure for usercomp@COMPANY.CORP from keytab krb5.usercomp.keytab: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user
>   ...
>
> Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user
>   at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForPass(Krb5LoginModule.java:856)

Is this the way to connect to Kerberized HBase from a Spark app?

Comment: have you missed conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "Kerberos"); ?

Answer (score 0):

please see the example configuration like below if you are missing anything like hadoop.security.authentication

```
val conf= HBaseConfiguration.create()
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "list of ip's")
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper"+ ".property.clientPort","2181");
conf.set("hbase.master", "masterIP:60000");
conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
```

Comment: I have this configuration in hbase-site.xml which is in the classpath of my app

Comment: Hi Can you pls check http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/cm_sg_sec_troubleshooting.html#topic_17_1_10

Comment: I guess the problem is with your keytab file

Comment: spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --executor-memory 4G  --num-executors 4 --executor-cores 2 --driver-java-options "-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true" --files "file.properties,hbase-site.xml,krb5.usercomp.keytab"  --class com.company.MyDriver test.jar

Comment: I can authenticate without any error with klist -e -k -t krb5.usercomp.keytab

Answer (score 0):

Actually try to put your hbase-site.xml directly in the SPARK_CONF directory of your edge node (should be something like /etc/spark/conf or /etc/spark2/conf).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI`, and `uig.doAs`

or you could put you hbase classpath to `SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH`.